# How to generate a frequency table from an array

Tags: r, frequency

I have an array like the following:

```
structure(c(0, 191, 235, 196, 311, 240, 246, 236, 222, 345, 369, 
447, 289, 274, 331, 368, 371, 344, 335, 403, 378, 367, 384, 364, 
191, 0, 230, 207, 336, 151, 291, 324, 306, 340, 389, 461, 345, 
322, 341, 367, 369, 356, 334, 395, 396, 392, 414, 387, 235, 230, 
0, 254, 309, 253, 300, 346, 305, 375, 400, 466, 379, 372, 367, 
387, 382, 370, 363, 445, 384, 361, 386, 356, 196, 207, 254, 0, 
298, 195, 263, 244, 223, 352, 377, 444, 348, 316, 333, 356, 367, 
347, 322, 400, 378, 357, 370, 367, 311, 336, 309, 298, 0, 326, 
257, 240, 259, 205, 320, 357, 331, 339, 191, 298, 262, 223, 220, 
311, 273, 216, 256, 317, 240, 151, 253, 195, 326, 0, 263, 308, 
277, 303, 382, 457, 347, 294, 321, 358, 374, 340, 302, 376, 386, 
373, 399, 379, 246, 291, 300, 263, 257, 263, 0, 264, 240, 265, 
283, 368, 263, 265, 268, 336, 324, 292, 262, 372, 354, 345, 359, 
355, 236, 324, 346, 244, 240, 308, 264, 0, 116, 307, 343, 412, 
296, 266, 299, 313, 320, 312, 308, 356, 320, 341, 353, 324, 222, 
306, 305, 223, 259, 277, 240, 116, 0, 280, 351, 428, 305, 263, 
308, 335, 350, 332, 314, 392, 362, 352, 372, 362, 345, 340, 375, 
352, 205, 303, 265, 307, 280, 0, 226, 303, 278, 287, 229, 349, 
312, 289, 238, 280, 361, 290, 326, 353, 369, 389, 400, 377, 320, 
382, 283, 343, 351, 226, 0, 290, 277, 265, 280, 344, 332, 360, 
332, 379, 391, 365, 370, 412, 447, 461, 466, 444, 357, 457, 368, 
412, 428, 303, 290, 0, 309, 346, 281, 345, 313, 336, 354, 334, 
349, 348, 337, 382, 289, 345, 379, 348, 331, 347, 263, 296, 305, 
278, 277, 309, 0, 147, 305, 333, 329, 355, 316, 339, 365, 358, 
385, 371, 274, 322, 372, 316, 339, 294, 265, 266, 263, 287, 265, 
346, 147, 0, 279, 303, 320, 346, 299, 318, 366, 358, 373, 378, 
331, 341, 367, 333, 191, 321, 268, 299, 308, 229, 280, 281, 305, 
279, 0, 201, 153, 172, 185, 254, 261, 228, 252, 316, 368, 367, 
387, 356, 298, 358, 336, 313, 335, 349, 344, 345, 333, 303, 201, 
0, 146, 235, 278, 287, 228, 299, 279, 235, 371, 369, 382, 367, 
262, 374, 324, 320, 350, 312, 332, 313, 329, 320, 153, 146, 0, 
184, 251, 233, 229, 264, 241, 273, 344, 356, 370, 347, 223, 340, 
292, 312, 332, 289, 360, 336, 355, 346, 172, 235, 184, 0, 157, 
202, 183, 193, 181, 249, 335, 334, 363, 322, 220, 302, 262, 308, 
314, 238, 332, 354, 316, 299, 185, 278, 251, 157, 0, 171, 221, 
178, 220, 262, 403, 395, 445, 400, 311, 376, 372, 356, 392, 280, 
379, 334, 339, 318, 254, 287, 233, 202, 171, 0, 149, 195, 168, 
218, 378, 396, 384, 378, 273, 386, 354, 320, 362, 361, 391, 349, 
365, 366, 261, 228, 229, 183, 221, 149, 0, 130, 127, 136, 367, 
392, 361, 357, 216, 373, 345, 341, 352, 290, 365, 348, 358, 358, 
228, 299, 264, 193, 178, 195, 130, 0, 98, 175, 384, 414, 386, 
370, 256, 399, 359, 353, 372, 326, 370, 337, 385, 373, 252, 279, 
241, 181, 220, 168, 127, 98, 0, 146, 364, 387, 356, 367, 317, 
379, 355, 324, 362, 353, 412, 382, 371, 378, 316, 235, 273, 249, 
262, 218, 136, 175, 146, 0), .Dim = c(24L, 24L))
```

and want to create a frequency table.

The code I have used:

```
ages <- c(-0.01,100,200,300,400,500,600)
factorx <- factor(cut(tdc,breaks=ages,include.lowest=TRUE))
xout <- as.data.frame(table(factorx))
```

gives

```
factorx     Freq
[-0.01,100]   26
(100,200]     52
(200,300]    168
(300,400]    308
(400,500]     22
```

which is right, except it excludes the interval 500 to 600. But the real problem is that the absolute frequencies are wrong as the sum should be equal to 25*25=625 but in xout is 576.

I guess there is a problem in the code.

Comment: `prod(dim(tdc))` and `length(tdc)` both give 576

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about, `str(tdc)` gives `num [1:24, 1:24]` and 24 * 24 = 576. That matches the last line of your data: ".Dim=c()24L, 24L)". Also `range(tdc)` is 0, 466. You do not need `factorx <- ` since the `cut` function returns a factor.